# Installing driver for CanoScan 9000F Mark II fails

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, 64-bit, scanner

The scanner worked previously, but it doesn't anymore. So I deinstalled all Canon software, incl. drivers using [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html). After restarting the laptop, I started the Canon driver installer [mp68-win-9000fmkii-1_00-ejs.exe](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0100004709/01/mp68-win-9000fmkii-1_00-ejs.exe), then followed the instructions on screen. The last step is connecting the scanner to a USB port and turning it on. Windows then tries to install the driver, but it fails:

[image: Screenshot of windows displayed during installation process]

I tried with two different USB ports, one USB 2.0 the other one 3.0. Other USB devices work fine with my machine, a ThinkPad T420si. The scanner also works fine, when connected with the same cable to a ThinkPad T550 running Linux.

What I also tried is opening Windows 7's *Scanners and Cameras*, then selecting *Add Device* / *Have Disk...*. I can select `CNQ9604.INF` which is included in the package from Canon, but then no scanners are listed:

[image: Screenshot of the Scanner and Camera Installation Wizard showing no scanners]

*What can I do? Where do I find log files that tell me what is happening?*

In the end I want to scan using VueScan, which I just bought.

## Update

As described in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1019249/why-did-i-have-to-copy-usbscan-sys), I solved the problem by copying `usbscan.sys` from `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Windows\inf` and restarting the driver installation process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did I have to copy usbscan.sys?](http://superuser.com/questions/1019249/why-did-i-have-to-copy-usbscan-sys)