# Why did I have to copy usbscan.sys?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, installation, 64-bit

When plugging in a Canon CanoScan 9000F, driver installation failed, and so I looked at the log file `C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log`: The file `usbscan.sys` could not be found in `C:\Windows\inf`.

So I searched for the file, and found it in a multitude of locations. From `C:\Windows\System32` I copied it to `C:\Windows\inf`, and now installation of the Canon driver works.

*But why did I have to manually copy `usbscan.sys`? Did the installer look in the wrong location, or has the file been deleted before?*

I wonder if there is something broken on my system.

Comment: Its not in the inf folder on my W7 either, was this windows trying to install the scanner or did you install from a cannon installer?

Comment: Mine (usbscan) was found in C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\

Comment: @Moab Windows driver installation started automatically after plugging in the scanner and turning it on. Concerning `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository`: On my system `usbscan.sys` can be found in the sub directories `sti.inf_amd64_neutral_972872c0e59df52d` and `sti.inf_amd64_neutral_9d9a7113099a28a2`.

Comment: I don't think you have an issue, and seems you solved the problem.

Comment: Sure, I solved the problem. Still, I don't understand why other Windows users don't need to copy `usbscan.sys`.

Comment: Its going to be difficult to solve that here.